# How to center absolute element with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have main div which is the `position:relative;` and children which is the absolute element.I want to centered them horizontally but there is something strange going on I don't understand.

How can i centered absolute element horizontally with flex? any idea with that ?

example image
[image]

```css
body{
  background:tomato;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  width:700px;
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
}
.block-item{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1){
  left:0;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(2){
  left:5%;
  top:25px;
  background:lightblue;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(3){
  left:10%;
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *absolute with flex* --> why? what is the purpose?

Comment: to centered my child element correctly

Comment: Flex doesn't correlate with absolute positioning. When you set `absolute: position` the  stacking context is being changed and the flex container no longer affect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: you can achieve this using `margin` as well or `position relative`

```css
body{
  background:tomato;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  padding:30px 10px 50px 10px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block-item{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:relative;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1){
  background:lightgreen;
  left:0;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(2){
    left: -2%;
    top: 20px;
    background: lightblue;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(3){
  left: -5%;
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but i need to set left and top my child elements

Comment: could you please show wireframe or something for how it should look?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need absolute position here. You simply need to adjust some margin to achieve this layout:

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
}

.block {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block-item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: -10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-item"></div>
    <div class="block-item"></div>
    <div class="block-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative` instead of *absolute* and add *flexbox* to `block` element. Also adjust *left* using pixels instead of percentages - see demo below:

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex; /* Flexbox here */
  justify-content: center;
}

.block-item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  position: relative;
  /*display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;*/
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: -20px; /* CHANGED */
  top: 25px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: -50px; /* CHANGED */
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-item"></div>
    <div class="block-item"></div>
    <div class="block-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background:tomato;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  width:700px;
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
}
.block-item{
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1){
  background:lightgreen;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(2){
  top:25px;
  background:lightblue;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(3){
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>      
      <div class="block-item"></div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLu14n3m/)

```
.block{
 position:relative;
 width:700px;
 background:white;
 padding:10px;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change css as below.

```
body{
    background:tomato;
}
.block{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    padding:10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.block-item{
    width:33%;
    height:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-item:nth-of-type(1){
    left:0;
    background:lightgreen;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(2){
    left:5%;
    top:25px;
    background:lightblue;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(3){
    left:10%;
    background:lightgray;
}
```

and there no change in html

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position:absolute` and use `position:relative` and adjust the top left right and center your main div as follow. I hope this solution will be helpful for you.

```css
body {
    background: tomato;
}
.block {
    max-width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}
.block-item {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: lightblue;
    top: 15px;
}
.block-item:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: lightgray;
    right: 30px;
    left: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-item"></div>
        <div class="block-item"></div>
        <div class="block-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```